# How to extract a particular frame from a video in openCV java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to extract a particular frame from a video using openCV java. For this, I am using the below code,

```
int tmsec;

VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

                    String input = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221005_013149.mp4";


                    cap.open(input);

                    Mat frame = new Mat();
                    cap.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, tmsec);
                    cap.read(frame);
                    if (Imgcodecs.imwrite("/storage/emulated/0/Images/testImg.jpg", frame)) {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failed");
                    }
```

the time in milliseconds for the frame is assigned to the variable 'tmsec' correctly(No error in that. That code is not shown here).

After running this code for several time with different values of 'tmsec', everytime I am getting the first frame instead of the specified frame.

What is the error in my code? Is there any error with 'cap.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, tmsec)' ? isn't that supported ?
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code or any alternative approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have OpenCV build with a support of a certain backend that supports `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`

From the [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d):

> Reading / writing properties involves many layers. **Some unexpected
> result might happens along this chain.** Effective behaviour depends
> from device hardware, driver and API Backend.

You can check your backend with `cap.getBackendName()` method - [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a4576e03f447abfdbd602c0809824ec03)

Here the general information about backends:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html

Also beware that `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` may work incorrectly for example in the case of videos with variable frame rate even with the working backends such as ffmpeg.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without using CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC  ?